# Continuous, injective map between annuli, but with a "hole" in the image

Tags: general-topology

In $\mathbb R^n$ let $B_r$ be the open ball with center zero and radius $r$. For $r\in (0,1)$ let $A_r = \overline{B_1}\setminus B_r$. Let $r,s\in (0,1)$ and assume that $F : A_r\to A_s$ is continuous and injective such that $F(\partial B_1) = \partial B_1$ and $F(\partial B_r) = \partial B_s$. Is it possible that the image of $F$ contains a hole in $A_s$, i.e., $F(A_r) = A_s\setminus U$, where $U$ is a connected open set?

Comment: Are you familiar with homology groups? This is a standard tool which provides a quick positive answer to this (and more general questions of this type).

Comment: Hi Moishe. I'm not. But is the answer yes or no? If you could compose an answer using these notions and pointing me to the appropriate theorems, I would be very happy. I would like to learn more about this stuff.

Comment: Wait...a *positive* answer? You CAN have a hole? That seems wrong to me for homology (or $\pi_1$) reasons.

Comment: @JohnHughes Oh, right. Moishe wrote "positive". Could you provide a counterexample?

Comment: I can prove that holes are *not* possible (or at least I think I can). I'll try to write it out.

Comment: When I said positive, I meant that the map has to be surjective.

Comment: Whew! I only do this stuff recreationally at this point, but it was tough to see how one could construct a non-surjective example.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof using invariance of domain theorem. Take your annulus $A_r$ and "double it" gluing two copies $A^\pm$ of $A=A_r$ along boundary spheres. The result is a connected closed (compact and with empty boundary) manifold $M$ (it is homeomorphic to $S^{n-1}\times S^1$ in case you are interested). The mapping $F: A\to A$ yields a continuous injective mapping $DF: M\to M$. Since $M$ is compact and $F$ is continuous, $DF(M)$ is also compact. Since $M$ is Hausdorff, $DF(M)$ is closed. By the [invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain#Generalizations) (this is where you need homology), $DF(M)\subset M$ is open. Since $M$ is connected, $DF(M)=M$. Thus, $F(A)=A$. qed

Edit. Let $(X,A)$ be a topological space $X$ with a closed subset $A$. The *double* $DX$ along $A$ is the quotient space of the product
$$
X\times \{0, 1\}
$$
(where $\{0, 1\}$ has the discrete topology)
by the equivalence relation $(a, 0)\sim (a, 1)$ for all $a\in A$. (The above product space is a disjoint union of two copies of $X$. The space $DX$ is informally described as obtained from that disjoint union by gluing two copies of $A$. It is an good exercise to understand the example when $X$ is the closed disk and $A$ is its boundary circle. Then $DX$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$.) Since $A$ is closed, $DX$ is Hausdorff, provided that $X$ is.
(Example: If $X$ is a manifold with boundary and $A=\partial  X$, then $DX$ is a manifold without boundary.)

Suppose that $f: (X,A)\to (Y,B)$ is a continuous map of pairs (i.e. $f(A)\subset B$), then one defines its double by
$$
Df: [(x, i)] \mapsto [(f(x), i)], i=0, 1. 
$$
Here bracket denotes the equivalence class as above. The map $Df$ is well-defined since $f(A)\subset B$. The map $Df$ is always continuous. If $f$ is injective, so is $Df$.

Comment: Thanks, Moishe. I will try to understand the details. I'll come back and either check and upvote your answer or ask more stupid questions. ;-)

Comment: @amsmath Sure, that's the right thing to do. There are no stupid questions but to there are stupid answers.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible. Let's pick $r = s$, and in fact work with an annulus $A$ of inner radius $1$ and outer radius $2$. And let's pick a point $P$ in the set $U$, so that $P$ is a point of $A$ such that $P \notin F(A)$. So we have our map,
$$
F : A \to A
$$
whose image misses $P \in A \subset \Bbb R^2$. Define
$$
\gamma_c
$$
to be a path starting at $(1,0)$ and travelling in a straight line to $(1+c, 0)$, then traversing a circle of radius $1+c$ counterclockise, and then returning to $(1,0)$, so that
$$
\gamma_c(t) = \begin{cases}
(1 + 3ct, 0) & 0 \le t \le \frac13 \\
((1+c)\cos(6\pi(t-\frac13)), (1+c)\cos(6\pi(t-\frac13))) & \frac13 \le t \le \frac23\\
(1 + t - 3(t-\frac23), 0) & \frac23 \le t \le 1
\end{cases}
$$

Then $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are homotopic loops in $\pi_1(A, a)$, where $a = (1, 0)$. And $\gamma_c$ is homotopic to these for all values of $0 \le c \le 1$. In particular, the loop $\alpha$ defined by $\gamma_0$ followed by $\gamma_1$ is null-homotopic in $\pi_1(A,a)$. That means that $F \circ \alpha$ is nullhomotopic in $F(A)$, hence (by inclusion) in $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{P\}, F(a)) = \Bbb Z$.

But $F \circ \alpha$ winds once around the point $P$ (OK, that takes a little proving, but not much), hence represents a nonzero element of $\pi_1(\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{P\}, F(a))$, which is impossible, because $F_\star$ is a homomorphism of groups, and cannot send $0$ to a generator.

Comment: Dear John, thank you very much. I should have added that I have a proof already for $n=2$ (via the Riemann mapping theorem and the Joran curve theorem). I was more interested in the case where $n > 2$. Can your proof be extended to that case? I don't know what $\pi_1(A,a)$ is...

Comment: Ah...I completely missed the "n" and thought this problem was for $\Bbb R^2$ only, which is why I used the fundamental group, $\pi_1$. (When I write $\pi_1(X, x_0)$, it means the group of homotopy-classes of loops in $X$ that start and end at $x_0 \in X$, called the "fundamental group." For $\Bbb R^n$, this definitely begs for the (homology) short exact sequence of a pair. I don't see a straightforward proof without using homology/cohomology.

Comment: John, If you have a proof using this terminology, please go ahead. Can I phrase it roughly as follows (?): $F : A\to F(A)$ is a homeomorphism, $\partial A$ (in $\mathbb R^n$) has two connected components, but $\partial F(A)$ (in $\mathbb R^n$) has three. That's not possible (by whatever homology-related theorem).

Comment: It's something like that, but ... I have a nagging worry about $F$ being defined only on $A$ rather than a neighborhood of $A$. It's been a while since I learned the relevant theorems.

Comment: John, you can define it as the identity in a neighborhood of $A$.

Comment: Uh...all you specified was that $F(\partial B_1) = \partial B_1$, which is an equality of *sets*; it doesn't tell me that $F(x) = x$ for $x \in \partial B_1$. Are you saying that $F$, restricted to $\partial B_1$, is actually the **identity** function on $\partial B_1$? (and similarly, with some radius adjustment, for the other boundary component?) If I define it as the identity in a neighborhood, then for continuity, I need it to be the identity on the boundary (pointwise, not setwise).

Comment: You're right. Actually, in my problem, I only have identity on the outer sphere. Also, the inner sphere actually isn't mapped to a sphere. It gets mapped to a hypersurface with the origin in its interior. I only assumed that because I thought they are homotopic anyways.